# How get type of property in CodeProperty ? T4

Tags: c#, t4

I included VisualStudioHelper. Here I getting all my classes by Attribute

```
var classesWithMapAttribute = VisualStudioHelper.GetClassesByAttributeName("Map", projectName);
```

After that I getting all properties in the Class.

```
    foreach (CodeClass pi in classesWithMapAttribute)
{ 
   var allProperties = VisualStudioHelper.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(pi.Members, vsCMElement.vsCMElementProperty, true);
}
```

That work perfectly. But I need get Types of properties. If I call

```
foreach(CodeProperty property in allPropertiesDto)
        {
             <#= property.Type #>
         }
```

I'll get ***System.__ComObject*** as result

Could you tell me, how get nested type of property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am ashamed that can't found answer before...

```
CodeTypeRef codeTypeRef = property.Type;
codeTypeRef.AsString // here we get type of property
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

Type t = property.PropertyType; // That will return a System.string

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please try to abstain from just code answers and try to actually explain what is happening, also always format your code

Comment: _property_ has type CodeProperty and doesn't have a definition PropertyType. **That's wrong for my situation**.